# Назначение прав на файл

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Еще один вопрос... На тему FileInfo. Как правильно провести процедуру назначения прав на файл? Как всегда не получается правильно инициализировать...

```
         FileInfo ^ info3 = gcnew FileInfo("D:\\CountIn.txt");
         FileSecurity^ fSec = gcnew info3->GetAccessControl();
         fSec->AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"MyDomain\MyAccessAccount", FileSystemRights->ReadData, AccessControlType->Allow);
         info3->SetAccessControl(fSec);
```

Comment: Простите если не в тему, но если это касается переноса файлов между ПК(любыми способами) - это не сработает. (этот комментарий навеян прошлым вопросом), и так же для Администраторов ПК это не сработает(доступ ограничен не будет).

Comment: К членам перечисления (enum) получаем доступ через два двоеточия: `FileSystemRights::ReadData`, `AccessControlType::Allow`.

Comment: Мой вам совет: переходите с C++/CLI на C#. Правда, после этого вам станут советовать сменить WinForms на WPF. А после перехода на WPF станут советовать сменить пол, ориентацию и страну проживания...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не подскажете, как инициализировать 
 
         FileSecurity ^ fSecurity = gcnew File::info3->GetAccessControl();.. 
Выдает ошибки: undeclared identifier...

Comment: Просто уберите `gcnew`. Это ключевое слово нужно при созаднии _нового_ объекта, а метод `GetAccessControl` возвращает уже _готовый_ объект. Итого: `FileSecurity^ fSec = info3->GetAccessControl();`.